# Can I use the original class as a type and still use its subclasses?

Tags: java, class, types, bukkit

I was working on this code and I happened to put the type as the original class.  Now if I plug the variable in with its subclasses (extended classes) it errors.  I'm running a Spigot plugin, but obviously this problem has nothing to do with Spigot itself but rather my lack of knowledge regarding Java.

I can't come up with any single solution and I've looked all over.

Edit (My Explaination): If you look at the PlayerClass, you will see a variable called Kit, it uses the KitClass type.  If you look at the KitClass it is a class that has one subclass called Alchemist.  My question is, does the KitClass type encompass all the inherited classes and original class?  If not then what type/modifications would I have to use for the Kit variable within PlayerClass in order for it to allow an instance of the Alchemist class to be set as the Kit variable?

```
package me.kckeith.KitPvP;

import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class PlayerClass {
    public Player Player;
    public double Coins;
    public KitClass Kit;

    public PlayerClass(Player Player, double Coins, KitClass Kit) {
        this.Player = Player;
        this.Coins = Coins;
        this.Kit = Kit;
    }

    public void setKit(KitClass Kit) {
        this.Kit = Kit;
        this.Kit.giveStuff();
    }
}
```

```
package me.kckeith.KitPvP;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;

public class KitClass {
    public Player Player;
    public Material InventoryIcon;

    public KitClass(Player player) {
        this.Player = player;
    }

    public void giveStuff() {
        Bukkit.getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Given items!");
    }
}
```

```
package me.kckeith.KitPvP.Kits;

import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.PotionMeta;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffect;
import org.bukkit.potion.PotionEffectType;

import me.kckeith.KitPvP.KitClass;

public class Alchemist extends KitClass {
    public static Material InventoryIcon = Material.SPLASH_POTION;

    public Alchemist(Player player) {
        super(player);
    }

    public void giveStuff() {
        // Clear items

        this.Player.getInventory().clear();

        // Give the player their armor

        ItemStack[] Armor = new ItemStack[4];
        Armor[0] = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_BOOTS);
        Armor[1] = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_LEGGINGS);
        Armor[2] = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_CHESTPLATE);
        Armor[3] = new ItemStack(Material.LEATHER_HELMET);

        // Add Enchants
        Armor[0].addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 1);
        Armor[1].addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 1);
        Armor[2].addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 1);
        Armor[3].addEnchantment(Enchantment.PROTECTION_ENVIRONMENTAL, 1);

        // Give Armor
        this.Player.getInventory().setArmorContents(Armor);

        // Give Golden Sword

        ItemStack GoldenSword = new ItemStack(Material.GOLDEN_SWORD);
        GoldenSword.addEnchantment(Enchantment.DURABILITY, 1);

        this.Player.getInventory().addItem(GoldenSword);

        // Give Regen Potions

        ItemStack RegenPotion = new ItemStack(Material.POTION, 4);
        PotionMeta RegenPotionMeta = (PotionMeta) RegenPotion.getItemMeta();
        RegenPotionMeta.addCustomEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.REGENERATION, 20, 2), true);
        RegenPotion.setItemMeta(RegenPotionMeta);

        this.Player.getInventory().addItem(RegenPotion);

        // Give Damage Potions
        ItemStack DamagePotion = new ItemStack(Material.SPLASH_POTION, 8);
        PotionMeta DamagePotionMeta = (PotionMeta) DamagePotion.getItemMeta();
        DamagePotionMeta.addCustomEffect(new PotionEffect(PotionEffectType.HARM, 0, 2), true);
        DamagePotion.setItemMeta(DamagePotionMeta);

        this.Player.getInventory().addItem(DamagePotion);

        super.giveStuff();
    }
}
```

The specific error I believe was NullStackException however I am not sure.  I got into more detail into this issue at the top of the code.

Comment: Sorry this is not clear.  What do you mean by "type" and "class"?  Also, post the ***actual*** stack trace, not just a piece of the error text, and indicate where the error occurred in your code.  Also read how to create a [mcve]

Comment: By type I mean the type used for a variable.  Like "ClassName NewClass = new ClassName();".  ClassName is the Type and the class.  I want to know what type I would use if I am trying to also include the inherited classes (Class extends ClassName) as a variable.

Comment: Please update your answer to include the whole error/stack trace.

Comment: Read the edit please, I explain in greater detail what my problem is an what I require in terms of a solution.

Comment: @kieranckeith you also read the comments: "post the actual stack trace" and about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - "error I believe was" is irrelevant, we need to know the real one

Comment: Good to read about SOLID principles. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is does the KitClass type encompass all the inherited classes and original class?

Yes it does, so when you create an `Alchemist` you can still use all of the KitClass methods. This would be correct: `Alchemist myAlchemistObject = new Alchemist(myPlayer);`

---

You have a lot of code that may be confusing. You should not have a Class and an object/variable with the same name.

For example, when declaring a variable this is not good:

```
public Player Player;
```

But this is clear and easy to read:

```
public Player player;
```

This is better again, and there will be no mixup/confusion:

```
public Player myPlayer;
```

Another example. This is unclear:

```
            PlayerClass PlayerClass = MainClass.PlayerList.get(Player.getUniqueId());
            Alchemist Alchemist = new Alchemist(Player);
            PlayerClass.Kit = Alchemist;
            PlayerClass.Kit.giveStuff();
```

And this is easy to understand:

```
            PlayerClass myPlayerObject = MainClass.PlayerList.get(myPlayer.getUniqueId());
            Alchemist myAlchemistObject = new Alchemist(myPlayer);
            myPlayerObject.Kit = myAlchemistObject;
            myPlayerObject.Kit.giveStuff();
```